# Texstudio and Texmaker won't work

Tags: miktex, installing, texmaker, texstudio

I tried to install Texmaker but it fails to compile any file. 
Instead it puts out the following error report (translated to english):

couldn't run order

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I have installed and run Miktex-portable before. A similar error occurs when I tried to use Texstudio.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed a TeX distribution?

Comment: Yes, Miktex is a Tex-Distribution.

Comment: Is pdflatex in your path?

Comment: For TeXstudio, can you try going to `Configure TeXstudio -> Commands`, and manually directing TeXstudio to `pdflatex.exe`? ([Click the blue folder icon for pdflatex](https://imgur.com/a/0BTc9)).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So which program am I supposed to choose after I click the folder icon? Sorry I am using Latex for the first time

Comment: @Dnk8000 Find `pdflatex.exe` on your system. For eg. mine is in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`, ymmv. Btw, if you would like me to be notified when you reply, you need to call `@Troy` like I did for you in this comment.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for helping me out @Troy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide the steps for TeXstudio, I presume it will be similar for TeXmaker (I don't use this editor...)

If you have already installed a TeX distribution (e.g. MikTeX, TeXLive) and an editor (in this case, TeXstudio), and you still experience this error, then you'll need to direct TeXstudio to the relevant engine (e.g., `pdflatex.exe`).

### Steps:

Under `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Commands`, click the blue folder icon for `PdfLaTeX`, like so:

[image]

When you click the icon, a window pops out asking you to find the `pdflatex.exe` program. If you installed MikTeX and used the default location (as I did), then you should be able to find `pdflatex.exe` at:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
```

Select it, and click ok, then you should be able to compile successfully.
The same can be done for the other engines.